# How to format url in php if have two value (?)

Tags: php

```
$url = 'http://test.com/?sort=newest&v=list?paged=3';
```

=> How to preg_replace this url to `http://test.com/?sort=newest&v=list&paged=3`

Answer (score 1):

If that's the the only kind of urls you need to edit, I would rather:

```
$str = str_replace("?", "&", $str);
$str = str_replace("&", "?", $str, 1);
```

So, change all the ? into &, then change only the first occurrence of & back to ?.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to explicitly use preg_replace then this will do the trick.

```
$url = preg_replace("/\?(.*?)(\?)(.*?)/", "?$1&$3", $url);
```

This will only replace a single question mark after the first one. If you have more then you can repeat it until only one question mark remains.

```
while(substr_count($url, "?") > 1)
{
    $url = preg_replace("/\?(.*?)(\?)(.*?)/", "?$1&$3", $url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get query string whith `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` , then replace `?` with `&`

```
   $str = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
   // $str = "sort=newest&v=list?paged=3?order=asc";
   $str = str_replace("?", "&", $str);
   echo $str;

   //output : sort=newest&v=list&paged=3&order=asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little function:

```
function cleanUrl($url) {
    //Replace all ? to &
    $url = str_replace('?', '&', $url);

    //Get position of first &
    $posFirst = strpos($url, '&');

    //Replace first & with ?
    return substr_replace($url,'?',$posFirst,1);
}

$newUrl = cleanUrl('http://test.com/?sort=newest&v=list?paged=3');
var_dump($newUrl); //string(43) "http://test.com/?sort=newest&v=list&paged=3"
```

But i think you have a design error. You can create a array of parameter, and then use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to build a query string.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$url = 'http://test.com/?sort=newest&v=list?paged=3';
$purl = parse_url($url);
$purl["query"] = str_replace("?","&",$purl["query"]);   // replace all '?' except first
$url = $purl["scheme"]."://".$purl["host"].$purl["path"]."?".$purl["query"];
echo $url;

// output
// http://test.com/?sort=newest&v=list&paged=3
```